# Return final value from traversing folder function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, filesystems

Question: Why won't a var `things` return a value from outside the `walk()` function? And how do I fix it?

Hypothosis:  this is async and the console.log is happening too early.  Which would lead me to how can I make this a `Promise` (i'm using node 4.1.1)

```
var walk = function(dir, done) {
  var results = [];
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var i = 0;
    (function next() {
      var file = list[i++];
      if (!file) return done(null, results);
      file = dir + '/' + file;
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          walk(file, function(err, res) {
            results = results.concat(res);
            next();
          });
        } else {
          results.push(file);
          next();
        }
      });
    })();
  });
};

function traverseDirectories() {
    var things = walk('src/', function(err, results){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(results) // ['dir/thing.png', 'dir/thing2.png']
        return results;
    });
    console.log(things) // undefined
};
traverseDirectories();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q. Why won't a var things return a value from outside the walk() function?

R. Because `walk` doesn't return anything (take a look and you''ll see that it's a `void` function).

---

Even if you make it a Promise, you won't be able to use it like:

```
var things = walk(...);
console.log(things);
```

Because Promises are thenable, and are still async, so it will be:

```
walk(...).then(function(things) {
  // do something with things here
});
```

---

To do what you want, you would need something that doesn't exist in current Javascript yet.

There is an [ES7 proposal of native `async/await`](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) that will be a *callback heaven*, but atm, you can use:

- [Async/Await library](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) (It's an amazing library, but very far from native, and performance isn't cool)
- ES7 transpiler - you can write the ES7 code today, and it will transpile for you to ES5 (e.g [Babel](http://babeljs.io/))

But, if you're already using the newest version of NodeJS (4.0.0 as the time of writing) - and if you're not, you really should - the best way of achieving what you want is to use *generators*.

Combined with a small library named **[co](https://github.com/tj/co)**, it will help you to achieve almost what the ES7 `async/await` proposes, and it will mostly use native code, so both readability and performance are really good:

```
var co = require('co');

var traverseDirectories = co(function *traverseDirectories() {
  var things = yield walk('src/');
  console.log(things) // there we go!
});

function walk(dir, results) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
      if (err)
        reject(err);

      var i = 0;
      (function next() {
        var file = list[i++];
        if (!file) resolve(results);
        file = dir + '/' + file;
        fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
          if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
            walk(file).then(function(res) {
              results = results.concat(res); 
              next();
            });
          } else {
            results.push(file);
            next();
          }
        });
      })();
    });
  });
}
```

You can read more about this subject [in this awesome Thomas Hunter's blog post](https://thomashunter.name/blog/the-long-road-to-asyncawait-in-javascript/).

Comment: When I run this now it I have to cmd+c to close it off.  Any ideas on how make sure the operation ends?  Is the promise not resolving? or something?

Comment: It's definally the promise not resolving :( any ideas (i'm a nerb)